# If this is checked on click undisable btn but if its unchecked again disable it

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there a better way to do this.

```
$('#termsAccept[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
              $('#qBtn').prop('disabled',false);
}


$('#termsAccept[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
            if ($(this).not(':checked')) {
              $('#qBtn').prop('disabled',true);
}
```

I want to combine the two into one click function

Comment: how do you do that? @Felix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
$('#termsAccept[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
     $('#qBtn').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

---

As @Karl-André Gagnon's suggestion, you should use `change` event for your `checkbox` instead of `click`:

```
$('#termsAccept').change(function() {
     $('#qBtn').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

As well as `id` is unique so you just need `#termsAccept`.

Comment: Just use `this.checked`

Comment: it should be `!this.checked`

Comment: @Felix better use `change` aswell.

Comment: @nol consider to use change event instead of click to handle all browsers, even older ones

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#termsAccept[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
              $('#qBtn').prop('disabled',false);
            }
            else {
              $('#qBtn').prop('disabled',true); 
            }
});
```